# Gatling report generation name customization

Tags: scala, testing, gatling

I would like to change the name of my reports generated by gatling automatically. I didn't find a feature or a library that exposes that behavior of gatling. Is there a way to achieve that without some hack?

Comment: Are you talking about the file names?

Comment: yes the resulting file names having the reports and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the name of the directory you keep the results from the `gatling.conf` file.

You can look at the following configuration:

```
directory {
      #data = user-files/data               # Folder where user's data (e.g. files used by Feeders) is located
      #bodies = user-files/bodies           # Folder where bodies are located
      #simulations = user-files/simulations # Folder where the bundle's simulations are located
      #reportsOnly = ""                     # If set, name of report folder to look for in order to generate its report
      #binaries = ""                        # If set, name of the folder where compiles classes are located: Defaults to GATLING_HOME/target.
      #results = results                    # Name of the folder where all reports folder are located
    }
  }
```

Comment: Yes, I knew that Gatling give you the flexibility around folders, where to create and what to name. But, it looks like it doesn't let you micro-config/manage the creation of reports. Thank you for the answer though, I appreciate it!